# Azure DevOps | Test Suite query to links test cases to user story

Tags: testing, azure-devops, wiql, test-plan

I'm trying to find a way in Azure DevOps so that my test cases will move from one suite to another when the linked User Story changes to a later sprint.  I have tried a query based suite, however, with my basic query it is filtering off the test case iteration and not the user story iteration.  What happens then is my test cases are left behind in the current sprint when the user story is moved to a future sprint.

1)  Is there a way have the test cases move to whatever sprint the user story moves to?

2)  Is there a way to write a test suite query so that when the story is moved to a future sprint, the test case is moved to the corresponding iteration suite?